# how to append optionValue to the input id and label for attribute dynamically?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

suppose options = ["low", "medium", "high"]

---

```
{{#each optionValue in options}}
    <span>
        <input type="radio" id="screen-risk-{{optionValue}}" name="riskRating"/>
        <label for="screen-risk-{{optionValue}}" name="checkbox"> Low </label>
    </span>
{{/each}}
```

how to append `optionValue` to the input id and label for attribute dynamically?

Without using any helpers, it should come like **screen-risk-low, screen-risk-medium, screen-risk-high**

Comment: What version of ember are you using?

Comment: what's wrong with your current code? It should just be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bound attribute syntax it's only supported in ember `>= 1.11.0`

See the [release blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_bound-attribute-syntax)

To get what you want, in the current version of ember (`1.10.0`). you can use [unbound](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound)

```
{{#each optionValue in options}}
    <span>
        <input type="radio" id="screen-risk-{{unbound optionValue}}" name="riskRating"/>
        <label for="screen-risk-{{unbound optionValue}}" name="checkbox"> {{optionValue}} </label>
    </span>
{{/each}}
```

But as described in the docs, it won't update if it changes:

> *unbound* allows you to output a property without binding. Important: The output will not be updated if the property changes. Use with caution.

See a [demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zigata/2/edit)

Comment: the question is nothing about attributes bindings